# How to add a class to another class that has a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, database, class

I have a system where users can log in and create boards. For this, there is the two separate classes 'User' and 'Board'.

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Board> Boards { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

public class Board
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

I have a webform to create a board and I'm getting a NullReferenceException whenever I try to run the site.

```
public partial class AddBoard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Board board = new Board();
    User user = new User();
    Utility utility = new Utility();

    static User loggedInUser;
    static Board boardToAdd;

    protected void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = NameTextBox.Text;
        loggedInUser = (User)Session["loggedInUser"];

        string checkName = utility.CheckBoardName(name);
        if (checkName == "OK")
        {
            boardToAdd.Name = name;
            boardToAdd.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            user.AddBoard(boardToAdd, loggedInUser);


        }
        else
        {
            CreateLabel.Text = checkName;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
boardToAdd.Name = name;
```

I am trying to call this method to add the board to the User class:

```
public User AddBoard(Board board, User user)
    {
        BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
        User _user = _context.Users.Find(user.ID);

        _context.Boards.Add(board);
        _context.Users.Add(user);
            return null;

    }
```

Edit: That error has been solved, but I'm still unable to create a board that is attached to the user. For clarification, each board has a 'User_ID' that should be the ID of the user who created the board.

Edit 2:

[This is the layout of the table for Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90bnu.png)

It consists of an ID, a name, the date it was created and the ID of the user who created the board.

Comment: You never instantiate boardToAdd so it will be null, You need to create a new instance of it. boardToAdd = new Board();

Comment: Thanks, the error no longer appears, yet my program is still not working. Now the error I get is an InvalidOperationException on the line '_context.Users.Add(user);'. Any reason why this error didn't occur for the loggedInUser?

Comment: You didn't have the problem with loggedInUser because you assign it a User from the session. Can you expand on the new Exception. What is the stacktrace saying?

Comment: I've deleted the line now and I'm not getting this second error anymore, however, I'm still unsure of how to add the board to the user class.

Comment: I know you are new to SO, so I need to explain that you shouldn't really be asking a new question in response to the answer of a question in the same question. (Now there is some sentence :) ) You should really ask a new question for new issues that arise.

Comment: Sorry, I asked that question last night about being unable to add the boards with the User_ID and got no responses.

Comment: Your AddBoard is ab it confusing, what you want to do. The name sounds you want to add a new board to something. But you add a new user to the database, and you search for an existing user in the database,without doing anything, with this existing user. I think your are not sure, what you want to do.

Comment: I want to add a new board. This new board is to be created by a user and as such the id of the user is an attribute for the boards. What I want to do is create a new board and attach it to the list of boards connected to the user.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because of you didn't initialized boardToAdd object, it's initial value is null.
Try creating instance of board.

static Board boardToAdd = new Board();

Comment: Thanks, I've added that in and it's solved the error, but I'm still unable to create a board that is attached to the user.

Comment: that's because you didn't related user and board classes correctly, add userId and User properties to board class and during insertion specify userId for board

Comment: I tried adding User_ID to the class, that simply made a second column in my table called User_ID2 and caused a whole load of issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't defined foreign keys. So you'll need to do something like.

```
public User AddBoard(Board board, User user)
{
    BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
    board.User_ID = user.ID;
    _context.Boards.Add(board);
        return null;

}
```

EDIT: I can't see a _context.SaveChanges() in your code. So you may need to add that if it isn't there.

If you have foreign keys defined:

```
Change the User Class to create a new HashSet of Boards something like:

public User() 
{
     Boards = new HashSet<Board>();
}
public User AddBoard(Board board, User user)
{
    BulletinContext _context = new BulletinContext();
    User _user = _context.Users.Find(user.ID);
    _user.Boards.Add(board);
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with that is that it can't find a definition for User_ID in Board.

Comment: Add it to your Board Class. public int User_ID {get; set;}

Comment: I tried doing that. It made a new column in the board table called 'User_ID2' and then there were numerous issues with it trying to drop the database while it was in use.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys defined?

Comment: There's the ICollection line and the User_ID column is marked as having a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Edited my asnswer